# Function arguments within Pandas pivot_table

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, pivot-table

I have wind direction and speed data in a Pandas data frame, in 10-minute slices. It looks like this:

```
      year  month  day  hour  minutes  direction  speed        filename
0   1999.0      1    1     0        0       84.0    7.1  mlrf1c1999.txt
1   1999.0      1    1     0       10       75.0    7.5  mlrf1c1999.txt
2   1999.0      1    1     0       20       79.0    7.2  mlrf1c1999.txt
3   1999.0      1    1     0       30       77.0    7.2  mlrf1c1999.txt
4   1999.0      1    1     0       40       76.0    6.7  mlrf1c1999.txt
5   1999.0      1    1     0       50       76.0    7.5  mlrf1c1999.txt
6   1999.0      1    1     1        0       81.0    6.9  mlrf1c1999.txt
7   1999.0      1    1     1       10       75.0    7.3  mlrf1c1999.txt
8   1999.0      1    1     1       20       77.0    7.4  mlrf1c1999.txt
9   1999.0      1    1     1       30       73.0    6.9  mlrf1c1999.txt
10  1999.0      1    1     1       40       78.0    6.5  mlrf1c1999.txt
11  1999.0      1    1     1       50       75.0    7.3  mlrf1c1999.txt
...
1147812  1997.0     12   31    21        0      261.0    6.0  mlrf1c1997.txt
1147813  1997.0     12   31    21       10      260.0    5.9  mlrf1c1997.txt
1147814  1997.0     12   31    21       20      262.0    5.5  mlrf1c1997.txt
1147815  1997.0     12   31    21       30      279.0    6.5  mlrf1c1997.txt
1147816  1997.0     12   31    21       40      283.0    7.3  mlrf1c1997.txt
1147817  1997.0     12   31    21       50      282.0    7.2  mlrf1c1997.txt
1147818  1997.0     12   31    22        0      277.0    6.9  mlrf1c1997.txt
1147819  1997.0     12   31    22       10      283.0    7.6  mlrf1c1997.txt
1147820  1997.0     12   31    22       20      283.0    7.2  mlrf1c1997.txt
1147821  1997.0     12   31    22       30      290.0    7.5  mlrf1c1997.txt
1147822  1997.0     12   31    22       40      289.0    7.2  mlrf1c1997.txt
1147823  1997.0     12   31    22       50      292.0    7.6  mlrf1c1997.txt
1147824  1997.0     12   31    23        0      296.0    7.7  mlrf1c1997.txt
```

I am trying to examine the data using a pivot table, so that I can get the mean direction and speed in hourly slices. I need to apply Scipy's circmean function to the directional data. This requires specifying high and low arguments for the dataset. When I attempt to do so, I get a TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable.

```
df.pivot_table(values = ['direction'], index = ['day', 'hour'], aggfunc = circmean(df.direction, high=df.direction.max(), low=df.direction.min()))

df.pivot_table(values = ['direction'], index = ['day', 'hour'], aggfunc = circmean(df.direction, high=360, low=0))
```

As I understand, circmean requires high and low arguments to get an accurate output. When I try to get the mean of the wind speed readings, using np.mean, I have no difficulty:

```
df.pivot_table(values = ['speed'], index = ['day', 'hour'], aggfunc = np.mean)
```

Which yields:

```
             speed
day hour          
1   0     6.085055
    1     6.144919
    2     6.253006
    3     6.315291
    4     6.305656
    5     6.241176
    6     6.205701
```

I can also apply the circmean function without parameters, like so:

```
df.pivot_table(values = ['direction'], index = ['day', 'hour'], aggfunc = circmean)
```

When I do this, I get results that I cannot interpret (that is, they are not in 360 degrees):

```
          direction
day hour           
1   0      2.992024
    1      3.414254
    2      1.620715
    3      0.463309
    4      6.206874
    5      1.451950
    6      4.319550
```

Is there a way to apply a function and arguments within the pivot_table's aggfunc parameter? If not, does anyone have a suggestion of how I could go about getting the circular means that I need from the data frame?

Comment: What is your original data, `df`? Please provide runnable code to replicate it.

Comment: Does that help? The original code is 100+ lines, and it's basically just loading the data frame and cutting it down to the data above. Np.mean and circmean are the first calculations I try to run on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code replicating your question:

```
import io
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import circmean

doc = """      year  month  day  hour  minutes  direction  speed        filename
0   1999.0      1    1     0        0       84.0    7.1  mlrf1c1999.txt
1   1999.0      1    1     0       10       75.0    7.5  mlrf1c1999.txt
2   1999.0      1    1     0       20       79.0    7.2  mlrf1c1999.txt
3   1999.0      1    1     0       30       77.0    7.2  mlrf1c1999.txt
4   1999.0      1    1     0       40       76.0    6.7  mlrf1c1999.txt
5   1999.0      1    1     0       50       76.0    7.5  mlrf1c1999.txt
6   1999.0      1    1     1        0       81.0    6.9  mlrf1c1999.txt
7   1999.0      1    1     1       10       75.0    7.3  mlrf1c1999.txt
8   1999.0      1    1     1       20       77.0    7.4  mlrf1c1999.txt
9   1999.0      1    1     1       30       73.0    6.9  mlrf1c1999.txt
10  1999.0      1    1     1       40       78.0    6.5  mlrf1c1999.txt
11  1999.0      1    1     1       50       75.0    7.3  mlrf1c1999.txt
1147812  1997.0     12   31    21        0      261.0    6.0  mlrf1c1997.txt
1147813  1997.0     12   31    21       10      260.0    5.9  mlrf1c1997.txt
1147814  1997.0     12   31    21       20      262.0    5.5  mlrf1c1997.txt
1147815  1997.0     12   31    21       30      279.0    6.5  mlrf1c1997.txt
1147816  1997.0     12   31    21       40      283.0    7.3  mlrf1c1997.txt
1147817  1997.0     12   31    21       50      282.0    7.2  mlrf1c1997.txt
1147818  1997.0     12   31    22        0      277.0    6.9  mlrf1c1997.txt
1147819  1997.0     12   31    22       10      283.0    7.6  mlrf1c1997.txt
1147820  1997.0     12   31    22       20      283.0    7.2  mlrf1c1997.txt
1147821  1997.0     12   31    22       30      290.0    7.5  mlrf1c1997.txt
1147822  1997.0     12   31    22       40      289.0    7.2  mlrf1c1997.txt
1147823  1997.0     12   31    22       50      292.0    7.6  mlrf1c1997.txt
1147824  1997.0     12   31    23        0      296.0    7.7  mlrf1c1997.txt"""    

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(doc), sep='\s+')
```

*Grumpy note: in a better question the code above is expected in question,
it taken a bit of unwanted excercise and time to replicate it in the answer.
See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for detail.*

```
# Now you need a function accepting an argument for `aggfunc`

def avg(x):
    # x will be a pd.Series, equalling df.direction
    return circmean(x, high=x.max(), low=x.min())
    
# just to learn how it works with 'mean'
df2 = df.pivot_table(values='direction', index=['day', 'hour'], aggfunc = 'mean')

# now putting the desired function
df3 = df.pivot_table(values='direction', index=['day', 'hour'], aggfunc = avg)
```

There is a warning, but I hope you know to handle it (perhaps you want to convert
degreees to radians inside `avg`):

> RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
> ang = (samples - low)*2*pi / (high - low)

Hope it helps.

Comment: It worked! Thank you, and apologies for the poor documentation on my part. I'm still learning this, so I appreciate the link. Incidentally, I didn't get the runtime warning. Thank you again, very much!

Comment: Maybe an older library on my part, but make sure foo does what it is intended for. Writing a good, focused question is hard - a good check for it is looking from outsider lens, and also allowing other people to replicate the problem by running code. Please,accept the answer if it suits.